# How can I validate an Ant XML file itself?

Tags: ant

I am using Ant files for build

The build itself is done by IBM Rational Team Concert (RTC) with the help of this Ant file.

My problem is that if I make a mistake in the build XML itself like wrongly typed attribute name, this itself is detected by RTC after loading the files from source control (normally 15-20 mins)

Is there a way to verify (validate) the Ant XML file itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no schema for an Ant XML. As explained in the [FAQ](http://ant.apache.org/faq.html#dtd) an incomplete DTD can be created but will not work:

> An incomplete DTD can be created by the  task - but this
>   one has a few problems:
>
> - It doesn't know about required attributes. Only manual tweaking of
>     this file can help here.
> - It is not complete - if you add new tasks via
>      it won't know about it. See this page by Michel Casabianca
>     for a solution to this problem. Note that the DTD you can download at
>     this page is based on Apache Ant 0.3.1.
> - It may even be an invalid DTD.
>     As Ant allows tasks writers to define arbitrary elements, name
>     collisions will happen quite frequently - if your version of Ant
>     contains the optional  and  tasks, there are two XML
>     elements named test (the task and the nested child element of )
>     with different attribute lists. This problem cannot be solved; DTDs
>     don't give a syntax rich enough to support this.

Comment: Thanks. Guess it's a hard work to get the fully functional DTD

Comment: @KarthikKrishnan Eclipse does some validation but in the end I disabled it since there were more wrong warnings as useful ones...

Answer (score 0):

Again, the FAQ states the DTD is not (yet?) powerful enough to do this, but I found a preliminary work for Ant 1.6 based on Michel Casabianca's work at [the AntDTD page on the Ant Wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/ant/AntDTD).  As for me, I do not intend to use it.